# How to look at correlation between dependent variable and independent variable with independent variable measured twice?

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have a dataset, where a cohort underwent two measurements (concentrations before and after surgery) and I now would like to see, whether those measurements show a correlation with a third measurement, which is a score of a test. The concentrations show a correlation with time/age and I think, the (sub)diagnosis is relevant for the test-score. I tried to use a mixed-effects model:

```
test score ~ concentration + age + diagnosis + (1|subject)
```

So I can account for the repeated measurement. Unfortunately, there are several issues. The model can't converge, it suggests rescaling of the variables, which I tried. (Did not solve the issue.) Now I was wondering whether there is perhaps a different solution to this type of question. Ideally, I would like to use all the data available, since the dataset has a limited size (60 subjects, 100 observations), but I also noticed interesting things such as, that the variance of the data is smaller around the second point of measurement (concentration after surgery).

Any recommendation on what I could try next would be apprechiated!

Comment: Since each subject has only 1 test score, you can't use a mixed model here. The dependent variable must be repeated in order to use a mixed model. Was the test administsred between the measurements, or before (or after) both ?

Comment: The test was administered after the 2 measurements.

Comment: @RobertLong Could you explain why it is not possible to use mixed models? Is it because if there is no repetition of the independent variable explaining the same dependent variable, that the random intercept of subject does not make any sense?

Comment: That is correct. Since you don't have repeated measures, or some other kind of nesting/clustering, it does not make sense to fit random intercepts.